# How to add padding in a bar chart between the outer bars and the left/right sides in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, padding, chart.js, chart.js2

When creating a bar chart in Chart.js all bars take up the whole horizontal space. How can I add some padding to the most left and most right bar to achieve what you see in the image below:

[image]

Alternativly this may be achieved if the bars are aligned in the center and using a max-width in percentage on the bars itself, so that they will never fill up the whole space. But I can't find any options for that either.

Currently I'm adding two `0` values with blank labels on each side, which works, but it's just a workaround:

```
var data = {
    labels: ['', '', 1, 2, 3, '', ''],
    datasets: [{
        data: [0, 0, 36500, 59000, 65000, 0, 0],

        backgroundColor: [
              null,null,
              'blue','blue','blue',
              null,null
        ],
    }]
};
```

I'm using Chart.js 2.3.